Output voltage didn't change after adding capacitors and resistors
I'm building a power supply that consists of a Type-C female to DPI adapter and a LD1117 voltage regulator (on a perfboard/protoboard). I was advised to add capacitors and resistors.

Before adding the capacitors and resistors, I checked the output voltage with a multimeter. It was 3.32V. After adding the them, it would fluctuate between 3.31v and 3.32V. Not I big change, I think.
Is this expected? Maybe I'll see the benefits of the capacitors and resistors when I use this circuit to power my HX711 load cell amplifier and ESP32-C3 (connected to Wi-Fi)?
Note: What I was expecting was to see more fluctuations before adding the capacitors and resistors.

Which exact LD1117 you mean and what resistors you mean? The LD1117 does not output 3.3V, unless you have voltage setting resistors on it, or you bought a fixed 3.3V version. It needs a load to output correct value. The caps are for stability, so if the voltage did not change then the regulator wasn't unstable to begin with. Please explain what are you trying to do and with what parts? If you mean CC resistors, that has got nothing to do with fluctuations, it's about getting power from supply or no power at all.


Not a big change, I think.   Is this expected?

Yes, that is expected.  Until a load is connected, your voltmeter will not show much difference between the two circuits.  The difference will be in the size of the ripple on the output voltage; for the same load current, the circuit with more capacitance will show less ripple (better).  The ripple measured from valley (min) to peak (max), aka "peak-to-peak", will be inversely proportional to the total capacitance.  BTW, you didn't mention the before and after values of the capacitance.
To really see the difference, you will need a scope - it may be possible to see this effect using your voltmeter set to AC rather than DC, but it depends on the capability of your voltmeter.
Note: From the link to Reddit, the extra resistors you mentioned are to tell the USB to supply full power, these won't affect this ripple too much.

The caps are there primarily to prevent the regulator IC from turning into an oscillator. With wrong caps with wrong impedance and ESR, it may still be unstable. Their secondary function is to be energy storage to filter ripple.

@Justme Yes, agreed & understood.  The OP already had 1 cap at both input & output of the linear regulator, I interpreted the question as being in regards to the specific measurement the OP made: ripple voltage. How would this measurement be different for this circuit if capacitance was increased. Cheers.

The (rather elderly) LD1117 is designed to work with an electrolytic 10uF (tantalum or aluminum type) capacitor on the output. It requires that part in order to be stable (in this context, that means to not oscillate). The input cap is not as fussy.
In case you want to use a ceramic capacitor you should insert a small value resistor in series with the 10uF capacitor (a few ohms) to ensure stability.
If you have the wrong type of capacitor, a very wrong value or if the capacitor is missing it could oscillate under some conditions of input voltage, output current, temperature etc.
Also, any regulator if you don't have adequate input and (especially) output capacitor can perform poorly when circuitry suddenly draws current or when the input voltage suddenly changes. It could droop, causing a reset in an MCU, it could overshoot. You won't likely see that difference in a multimeter (unless it's oscillating) but if you have an oscilloscope and connect a circuit that draws sharp pulses of current it will be very obvious.
